# monit, let's encrypt, and file permissions

Tags: centos7, monit, certbot

I decided to put monit on my vps running centos 7. 
I've already got let's encrypt on the server and the certs are installed. I wanted to point monit at the fullchain.pem or the cert.pem, but I get this error.

```
    Dec 30 00:56:52 [23926]: The SSL server PEM file 
    '/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem' must have permissions no more than -rwx------ (0700); right now permissions are -rw-r--r-- (0644).
    Dec 30 00:56:52 monit[23926]: /etc/monitrc:131: SSL server PEM file permissions check failed 'allow'
    Dec 30 00:56:52  systemd[1]: monit.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

Not sure how to proceed. Do I change the owner of the cert files? Do I change the owner who runs monit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Monit is quite strange in that it expects the private key and TLS certificate chain to be concatenated into a single file specified by `pemfile`, so you can't use certificates retrieved with certbot without some further processing.

You will need to set up a [deploy hook](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#renewing-certificates) in certbot in order to [concatenate the certificates into a single file](https://bitbucket.org/tildeslash/monit/issues/475/httpd-set-public-private-key-separately) and set permissions on that file.

An example script might look like:

```
#!/bin/bash

for domain in $RENEWED_DOMAINS
do
    case $domain in
    example.com)
        cat $RENEWED_LINEAGE/privkey.pem $RENEWED_LINEAGE/fullchain.pem > /etc/monit/pemfile-$domain.pem
        chmod 600 /etc/monit/pemfile-$domain.pem
        ;;
done
```

Then renew with `certbot renew --deploy-hook '/path/to/that/script.sh'`.

And in monit specify `pemfile /etc/monit/pemfile-example.com.pem`

Finally, you can restart monit with the renewed cert with something like a certbot renew `--post-hook 'systemctl restart monit'`...

Answer (score 3):

As of [Monit v5.27.0](https://mmonit.com/monit/changes/#5.27.0), released 2020-06-29, you can now pass in pemchain and pemkey parameters pointing to the separate files that Let's Encrypt generates. Quoting from the [documentation](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#SSL-settings):

> As an alternative *PEMCHAIN* and *PEMKEY* sets the path to separate PEM
> encoded certificate chain and private key file. The key file should be
> stored in a safe place on the filesystem and should have strict
> permissions, no more than 0700.
>
> ...
>
> Example for using separate certificate chain and key:
>
> ```
> set httpd
>     port 2812
>     with ssl {
>        pemchain: /etc/ssl/certs/monit.chain.pem
>        pemkey: /etc/ssl/certs/monit.key.pem
>     }
>     allow myuser:mypassword
> ```

See also: [PR #78](https://bitbucket.org/tildeslash/monit/pull-requests/78).

Comment: Syntax error ssl { here